# Restart Django database connection after updating database settings in tests

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-tests, pytest-django

In my Django settings, I have a setting called `POSTGRES_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT` that allows me to configure a [statement timeout](https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/statement_timeout/). I'm setting the deafault to 30 seconds. Note, I'm using [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) to manage my environment variables.

```
# settings.py

env = environ.Env(
    POSTGRES_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT=(str, "30s"),
)

POSTGRES_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT = env("POSTGRES_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT")
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        ...
        "OPTIONS": {
            "options": f"-c statement_timeout={POSTGRES_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT}s"
        },
    }
}
```

I want to write a simple test to ensure the postgres statement timeout setting works properly. Note I'm using pytest-django.

```
# tests.py

def test_statement_timeout(settings):
    # Lower statement timeout so this test doesn't take 30s to run.
    settings.POSTGRES_STATEMENT_TIMEOUT = "1s"

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        with pytest.raises(OperationalError) as exc:
            cursor.execute("select pg_sleep(2)")

    assert "canceling statement due to statement timeout" in str(exc.value)
```

This test is failing. When I print `settings.DATABASES` I see the statement timeout is still 30 second, not 1 second.

Even if I override `settings.DATABASES` directly via `settings.DATABASES["default"]["OPTIONS"] = {"options": "-c statement_timeout=1s"}`, the test still fails.

I think I need to restart the database connection after updating the settings. Is there anyway to do this in the tests?